# Runtime error 13 Type Mismatch VBA to highlight row if value is found in another workbook

Tags: excel, runtime-error, excel-2013, vba

I'm learning VBA in Excel 2013 and I posted a question last weekend but didn't receive a response. I've been working on the code more and narrowed the error down to one. I'm trying to highlight a row in a workbook if a value in column A is found in the column A another open workbook.

I get a Runtime error 13: Type mismatch error. That is all that it says and it is for this line of code:

```
If cell.Value = valuetofind Then
```

I have looked on numerous sites about this error but I don't see any that match my situation. I think it's b/c 'valuetofind' is a range and it's trying to set a range equal to a value, seen in 'cell.value'. I think all of my variables are declared properly.

I've tried changing it to below so that they are both ranges but that gives the same error:

```
If cell = valuetofind Then...
```

Can anyone help with this error?

```
Sub HighlightRow()
'http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?26162-Solved-Highlight-ROW-based-on-cell-value
'http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/827262-visual-basic-applications-vlookup-between-2-workbooks.html
     'test column just picks any column, I think, to test how far down the rows go to, I think you could choose any column
    Const TEST_COLUMN As String = "D" '<=== change to suit
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim valuetofind As Range

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 'name will change each day
    Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1) 'name will change each day

    With ws1
        LastRow = Cells(.Rows.Count, TEST_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Row
    'LastRow is testing/finding out last row using TEST_COLUMN first before performs rest of macro
    End With

    Set valuetofind = ws2.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
         'Range("A2:A" & LastRow) is the criteria row where it is looking for Break Down and PM/SM Call below
         'Resize(,7) will highlight the row however many columns you tell it to, in this case 7
         'cell.Offset(, -6) I think tells to go back 6 columns to column A and start the highlighting there
    With ws1
        For Each cell In Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
            If cell.Value = valuetofind Then
            'old, do not use: wb2.Worksheets(wb2SheetName).Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
                cell.Offset(, -6).Resize(, 7).Interior.ColorIndex = 39
            Else
                cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone can view this since it is old, but can anyone help regarding this. I'm still having issues with this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has been altered and is working for anyone who needs help.

This is modified from Dinesh Takyar's video on copying data between worksheets(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AzhQ5KiNybk_), though this code below is to highlight rows between workbooks. Both workbooks, destination and source workbooks, need to be open.

I believe the original Run Time 13 Error was b/c the criteria, original variable called 'valuetofind' was Dim as Range, when it is a String. The variable in the code below is now called 'myname' and is Dim as String. But I don't believe the code above would have worked anyway b/c I needed the For/Next to go through each cell in my criteria column.

Thanks to Dinesh and people on this forum.

```
Sub HighlightRowBtwWorkbook()


Dim wkbkDest As Workbook
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrowDest As Long
Dim lastcolDest As Long
Dim wkbkSource As Workbook
Dim j As Long
Dim lastrowSource As Long
Dim myname As String
Dim lastcolSource As Long

'Destination
Set wkbkDest = ThisWorkbook 'was Workbooks("Destination_VBAHighlight.xlsm") 'was ActiveWorkbook
lastrowDest = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastcolDest = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 2 To lastrowDest
myname = wkbkDest.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value

'Source
Set wkbkSource = Workbooks("TESTVBA.xlsm")
wkbkSource.Activate
lastrowSource = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastcolSource = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For j = 2 To lastrowSource
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(j, "A").Value = myname Then
        'Activate Destination
        wkbkDest.Sheets(1).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, "B"), Cells(i, lastcolDest)).Interior.Color = RGB(252, 228, 214)
    End If
Next j

Next i

'select cell A1 in Destination wkbk to end there
wkbkDest.Sheets(1).Activate
wkbkDest.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select


End Sub
```